# Calling DeleteAllItems method on wx.TreeCtrl object takes a very long time

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have written a small application used to parse data from a data set and display it in wx visual with several different files. The displayed elements are all in one notebook object on separate pages. A few are wx.TextCtrl/wx.StyledTextCtrl objects and the others are wx.TreeCtrl objects.

One particular wx.TreeCtrl object gets populated with upwards of 2000 branches.

Creating the tree and filling it:

```
data_tree = wx.TreeCtrl(data_page, style=wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
data_to_parse = utils.getData()  # This returns a list of objects with data string
root = data_tree.GetRootItem()

for entry in data_to_parse:
    # The method (utils.isMatch())is used to verify contents in the string. 
    # If there is a match the string is used to create a tree entry.
    if utils.isMatch(entry.data):  
        data_tree.AppendItem(root, text=entry.data)
```

When calling the DeleteAllItems() method:

```
data_tree.DeleteAllItems()
```

I have noticed that when the application calls the DeleteAllItems() method on this particular tree there is a very long wait time (5-10 seconds) before the method returns. This is causing a long delay in closing out the application when the tree is populated. Since this tool is used on the fly to assess problems with data sets it is important to make the tool quick to open/close as necessary.

My question is regarding the performance of DeleteAllItems on wx.TreeCtrl objects. Is this the only way to free these resources? Is there a more time efficient alternative?

I know that it might be recommended to reduce the number of actively loaded elements in the tree, but this is not desirable as consumers use the full data set in this tree to understand flow of events as well as the data in each event.

Comment: can you show some code? specifically, how do you create the tree control.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why does this take so long for you. 2000 branches is a lot and arguably more than reasonable upper limit (consider using `wxDataViewCtrl` if you need really many items), but deleting them still shouldn't take 10 seconds.

Do you have any `wxEVT_TREE_DELETE_ITEM` handlers in your code? They will be executed for each and every item being deleted, so if you do, make sure to unbind them before deleting the tree.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find a workaround.

Calling os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM) allows my application to exit quickly and Windows handles the memory cleanup.